People and information intermingling app/site/network
I am looking for a social network platform that works on computers and smartphones such as Android.
I am looking for some social network where you can post a page to the social network and make arrangements with people found on or suggested by the network, to engage in a study session on the posted page and information for generating ideas for doing stuff in real life (for, example, in one's real life or in order to suggest to tell life contacts), to, do something (with the information).
Learning, is fun.
There are sites live Wikipedia, which, post, loads, of information.
However, we need a social network, where, wanting, or prospective, engagers, can post pages, and, let the post wait for people to join (who want to learn that thing, ), and you receive notifications on your phone of when the contacts are available and go back and click to say ,"yes, I want to try and learn and discuss this, with, this person, at that time".
Then, you, meet.
Once you have learned something with someone (mutual help, questioning, suggesting, and acting), you, can, at a later time, get back, to, that contact, on your social network, and, feel affection, get interested, feel like you are next to our like you are, that person, and, contribute, as a support that also gains affection in the midst of the action, for doing something or viewing that someone, do, something... with the information learned.
The topic, may, be arbitrary.
But if you can post to a social network to get involved with a person or group of people (searching, people, and meeting up on video), to study, the page, in question (and discuss what each person wants to do with the information based on what lies in each person's life (real, life, experiences, for example), which are personal to the people involved.
Based on the learning, contribution, and speed, the network can suggest learners.
